# How do I set a service startup type to be 'Automatic (delayed)' using GPO?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-service

A Windows service has 4 different startup types that can be configured: Automatic, Automatic (delayed), Manual and Disabled.

I have a service running on a combination of Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 Desktops that I need to set as 'Automatic (delayed)' using a GPO setting, but from what I can see in the GPO editor, the delayed option is missing:

[image]

Have I missed something obvious, or is this a rather basic omission from Microsoft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to user ***Services preference*** extension which allows to configure existing services on client machines via GPO.

[More options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732482.aspx) for configuring services via GPO. Should work with W7, haven't tried on earlier client versions.

[image]