# Set service StartType to Automatic - Delayed

Tags: powershell, windows-service, startup

Using [`Set-Service`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service), I'm able to change the `StartType` of my services between the accepted values of `Boot, System, Automatic, Manual, Disabled`. Using `services.msc`, I'm able to set some services to startup with a Priority of <kbd>Automatic (Delayed Start)</kbd>. However, `Get-Service` still reports these delayed-start services as `StartType : Automatic`, and `Set-Service` errors out when attempting to set these values.

Am I able to set this property via powershell? Or am I limited to the UI [or GPO](https://serverfault.com/questions/452262/how-do-i-set-a-service-startup-type-to-be-automatic-delayed-using-gpo)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PowerShell 6.0 has added the option StartType to Automatic - Delayed in Set-Service cmdlet

ex: Set-Service -Name "Testservice" –StartupType "AutomaticDelayedStart"

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 27):

No direct way in PowerShell, just use `sc`

```
sc.exe config NameOfTheService start= delayed-auto
```

in older versions of Windows you needed a space after the equal sign, this doesn't seem to be required anymore but it still works.

You can also change the registry keys:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NameOfTheService\Start = 2
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NameOfTheService\DelayedAutostart = 1
```

Comment: calling `sc.exe` directly makes it easy to pipe the result for later handling. as well - this answer gave me the idea to just query the registry directly with [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) to determine if the service is DelayedAutostart.

Answer (score 8):

There is no simple way to do it using powershell cmdlets. In my opinion the easiest way is to use sc.exe. Here is one way to do that:

```
$myArgs = 'config "{0}" start=delayed-auto' -f 'TheServiceName'
Start-Process -FilePath sc.exe -ArgumentList $myArgs
```

Comment: My version require a space after the equal sign

Answer (score 3):

The catch is to use "StartupType" instead of "StartType" when you are searching for "AutomaticDelayedStart, which is introduced in PowerShell 6.

After a bit of trial and error and error, this worked for me:

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.StartupType -eq "AutomaticDelayedStart"} | Sort-Object status
```